# Entity Framework update lookup table is adding items to another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an issue with a lookup table.
I have a form that allows me to select colours from a list that will be part of a team.
The update method looks like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
/// <summary>
/// Update a team
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The team model</param>
/// <returns>Nothing</returns>
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Update(TeamBindingViewModel model)
{

    // If our model is invalid, return the errors
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // Get our current team
    var team = await this.service.GetAsync(model.Id, "Colours");

    // Make changes to our team
    team.Name = model.Name;
    team.Sport = model.Sport;

    // Find out which colours need adding and removing
    var coloursToRemove = GetDifference(team.Colours, model.Colours);
    var coloursToAdd = GetDifference(model.Colours, team.Colours);

    // Loop through our colours to remove and remove them
    if (coloursToRemove.Count() > 0)
        foreach (var colour in coloursToRemove)
            team.Colours.Remove(colour);

    // Loop through the colours to add and add them
    if (coloursToAdd.Count() > 0)
        foreach (var colour in coloursToAdd)
            team.Colours.Add(colour);

    // Update the team
    this.service.Update(team);

    // Save the database changes
    await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Return Ok
    return Ok(model);
}

private IList<Colour> GetDifference(IList<Colour> firstList, IList<Colour> secondList)
{

    // Create a new list
    var list = new List<Colour>();

    // Loop through the first list
    foreach (var first in firstList)
    {

        // Create a boolean and set to false
        var found = false;

        // Loop through the second list
        foreach (var second in secondList)
        {

            // If the first item id is the same as the second item id
            if (first.Id == second.Id)
            {

                // Mark it has being found
                found = true;
            }
        }

        // After we have looped through the second list, if we haven't found a match
        if (!found)
        {

            // Add the item to our list
            list.Add(first);
        }
    }

    // Return our differences
    return list;
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on the **unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync()** then I can see that the team colours is using the existing colours already in my database (all the id's match up.
But once that **SaveChangesAsync** executes, it creates a new row in the Colours table with a duplicate of the colour I just selected.
I don't want it to create a new row, I want it to use the selected colour.

I am not sure how I can give more information; I hope this is enough of a description for someone to be able to help me!

**Update**

So I have decided to look at the SQL that is generated.
I have a colour in my **Colours** table that looks like this:

> > 10   Red (Pms200)    ff0000

So the **Id** is **10**, the **Name** is **Red (Pms200)** and the **Hex** is **ff0000**.
If I select that colour when editing a team and press submit. It runs the **Update** method shown above and I have changed my **DbContext** to log the sql by adding this line in the constructor:

```
this.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

So, when the **SaveChangesAsync** code exectues, the following SQL is generated:

```
Started transaction at 13/04/2015 12:25:03 +01:00

UPDATE [dbo].[Teams]
SET [Name] = @0, [Sport] = @1
WHERE ([Id] = @2)

-- @0: 'Testing' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @1: 'ultimate-frisbee' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @2: '1' (Type = Int32)

-- Executing asynchronously at 13/04/2015 12:25:03 +01:00

-- Completed in 5 ms with result: 1



INSERT [dbo].[Colours]([Name], [Hex])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Colours]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()


-- @0: 'Red (Pms200)' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @1: 'ff0000' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- Executing asynchronously at 13/04/2015 12:25:03 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



INSERT [dbo].[TeamColours]([TeamId], [ColourId])
VALUES (@0, @1)

-- @0: '1' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: '43' (Type = Int32)

-- Executing asynchronously at 13/04/2015 12:25:03 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: 1



Committed transaction at 13/04/2015 12:25:03 +01:00

Closed connection at 13/04/2015 12:25:03 +01:00
```

Now the problem here is that it should be only inserting something into the **TeamColours** table and not the **Colours** table.
I can't figure out why....

And because someone has asked to see my **UnitOfWork** class, here it is:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> repositories;

    public DbContext Context { get { return this.context; } }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        this.context = new TContext();
        repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
            return repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IRepository<TEntity>;

        var repository = new Repository<TEntity>(context);

        repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repository);

        return repository;
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            ex.Entries.First().Reload();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Although I am certain that is not causing the issue.

Comment: what are you doing inside unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(), can you please share the code of that? 

EDIT: I'm too a beginner, but I think that you are using different contexts, that's it isn't updating existing rows, but rather adding new row, and furthermore the code inside the mentioned method is also worth detaining in my opinion.

Comment: This is likely one of the pifalls in hiding EF using the repository pattern... At a guess you need to `Attach` the colours that are part of the passed `model`.  Unless they are being tracked by the `DbContext` state tracker, EF will assume they are new.  An alternative is to select  instances of the `Colour` from the repository and add those to `team.Colours` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Model.Colors is not associated a context.  So your Db Context tries to add new one.

1 -Get colors from repository

```
var newColours = repository.ListColours(model.Colors.Select(m=>m.Id));
```

2- Assign new colors to team

```
team.Colours = newColours;

this.service.Update(team);

await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

EF will automatically operate remove and add operations.

I have not tested this code. But I hope EntityFramework smarter then I thought.

Comment: If I use this to add the colours when there are none, it works fine. If I try to use this when there are colours, it fails stating An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.",

Comment: yeah it looks like EF is not smart enough to automatically remove and add records.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Update(TeamBindingViewModel model)
{
    // If our model is invalid, return the errors
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // Get our current team
    var team = await this.service.GetAsync(model.Id, "Colours");

    // Make changes to our team
    team.Name = model.Name;
    team.Sport = model.Sport;

    //remove
    foreach (var colour in team.Colours.ToList())
    {
        if (!model.Colours.Any(c => c.Id == colour.Id))
            team.Colours.Remove(colour);
    }

    //add
    foreach (var colour in model.Colours)
    {
        if (!team.Colours.Any(c => c.Id == colour.Id))
            team.Colours.Add(colour);
    }

    // Update the team
    this.service.Update(team);

    // Save the database changes
    await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Return Ok
    return Ok(model);
}
```

Comment: Hi, This caused the same problem.

Comment: you may have some thing wrong with ur design ,,, It must work i think... show more details