# Eager loading entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So, [I was having a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603471/entity-framework-update-lookup-table-is-adding-items-to-another-table) and in order to fix it, I have created an Entity for the TeamColour table. This has allowed me to create my Create/Update methods like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
/// <summary>
/// Create a team
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The team model</param>
/// <returns>Nothing</returns>
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(TeamBindingViewModel model)
{

    // If our model is invalid, return the errors
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // Create our new model
    var team = new Team()
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Sport = model.Sport
    };

    // Create a new transaction incase anything fails, it will rollback the changes
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        // Otherwise, create a new team
        this.service.Create(team);

        // Save the database changes
        await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

        // For each colour, insert into our lookup table
        foreach (var colour in model.Colours)
            this.teamColourService.Create(new TeamColour { ColourId = colour.Id, TeamId = team.Id });

        try
        {

            // Save the database changes
            await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        // If everything is done correctly, call the complete method
        transaction.Complete();
    }

    // Return Ok
    return Ok(model);
}

[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
/// <summary>
/// Update a team
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The team model</param>
/// <returns>Nothing</returns>
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Update(TeamBindingViewModel model)
{

    // If our model is invalid, return the errors
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // Get our current team
    var team = await this.service.GetAsync(model.Id, "Colours");

    // Make changes to our team
    team.Name = model.Name;
    team.Sport = model.Sport;

    // Update the team
    this.service.Update(team);

    // For each colour that has to be removed, remove from our team colours
    foreach (var colour in team.Colours.ToList())
        if (!model.Colours.Any(c => c.Id == colour.Id))
            this.teamColourService.Remove(new TeamColour { ColourId = colour.Id, TeamId = model.Id });

    // For each colour that has to be added, add to our team colours
    foreach (var colour in model.Colours)
        if (!team.Colours.Any(c => c.Id == colour.Id))
            this.teamColourService.Create(new TeamColour { ColourId = colour.Id, TeamId = model.Id });

    // Save the database changes
    await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Return Ok
    return Ok(model);
}
```

Which solves my problem in my original question.
The problem I have now, is that since creating entities for my lookup table, when I use eager loading, nothing is pulled back for the colours. For example, here is my get method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
/// <summary>
/// Gets a team by the id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The id of the team</param>
/// <returns>A team</returns>      
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    return Ok(await this.service.GetAsync(id, "Colours", "Players", "Kits"));
}
```

As you can see, this is trying to get the Team and also pulling back Colours, Players and Kits.
If we look at the Team class, we will see the children defined:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sport { get; set; }

    public IList<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
    public IList<Kit> Kits { get; set; }
    public IList<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Before I created the Lookup table as an actual Entity, The Colours would be pulled back, but they were inserting new records into the Colours and TeamColours table rather than just the TeamColours table.
Like I have said, creating the TeamColours table as an entity fixed that, but appears to have broken the eager loading.
My database context looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{

    // Define our tables
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Design> Designs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Kit> Kits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TeamColour> TeamColours { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// static constructor (only gets called once)
    /// </summary>
    static DatabaseContext()
    {

        // Create the database and insert our records
        //Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new DatabaseInitializer());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

        // Disable Lazy Loading
        base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        // Write our SQL to the debug window
        this.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overrides the inherited OnModelCreated method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder">The DbModelBuilder</param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        // Remove Cascading Delete
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        // Map the UserRoles table
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Roles)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                m.ToTable("UserRoles");
            });

        // Map the KitColours table
        modelBuilder.Entity<Kit>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Colours)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("KitId");
                m.MapRightKey("ColourId");
                m.ToTable("KitColours");
            });

        //// Map the TeamColours table
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
        //    .HasMany(m => m.Colours)
        //    .WithMany()
        //    .Map(m =>
        //    {
        //        m.MapLeftKey("TeamId");
        //        m.MapRightKey("ColourId");
        //        m.ToTable("TeamColours");
        //    });

        // Create our relationships
        modelBuilder.Entity<Kit>().HasRequired(m => m.Team).WithMany(m => m.Kits).Map(m => { m.MapKey("TeamId"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Kit>().HasRequired(m => m.Design).WithMany().Map(m => { m.MapKey("DesignId"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasRequired(m => m.Team).WithMany(m => m.Players).Map(m => { m.MapKey("TeamId"); });

        // Add our keys to the lookup tables
        modelBuilder.Entity<TeamColour>().HasKey(model => new { model.TeamId, model.ColourId });
    }
}
```

So, my questions is, how can I get my eager loading to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, I fixed this by changing the virtual property to this:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sport { get; set; }

    public IList<TeamColour> Colours { get; set; }
    public IList<Kit> Kits { get; set; }
    public IList<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

I was only interested in the **colourId** anyway, so this works fine.

Comment: I guess I could have done something like return Ok(await this.service.GetAsync(id, "Colours.Colour", "Players", "Kits")); if I really needed the other fields associated to Colour